# How to load a marshaled hash with a ":value" key

Tags: ruby, hash, load, marshalling, symbols

```
File.write("a",Marshal.dump({ :value => 1 }))
Marshal.load(File.open("a"))
```

This produces:

```
c:/tmp/a.rb:9:in `load': end of file reached (EOFError)
from c:/tmp/a.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

While this:

```
File.write("a",Marshal.dump({ :valu => 1 }))
Marshal.load(File.open("a"))
```

works.

`:value` seems to be 'reserved'. Am I wrong or crazy?

Comment: can't reproduce. both code samples work and none throws an exception

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? I tried this on ruby 1.9.3p484, ruby 2.2.1p85 and ruby 2.3.0p0 and it works fine on all of them. I see you are on windows, I am on ubuntu. I wonder if that has something to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!
The file must be open in 'wb' mode on Windows. Otherwise, it produces strange results.